# ERROR TypeError: _co.saveXML is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

In my client Angular project I have a component called report-viewer. Inside it I have a form, EmailSettings, which is called when a button from component is pressed.

[image]

The form code is the following:

**EmailSettings.html**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Email Settings</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <form id="formID" class="example-form">
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="data.smtpHost === ''" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>SMTP Host</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex: smtp.gmail.com"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field> <br>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="data.smtpPort === ''" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>SMTP Port</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex: 587"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field> <br>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="data.smtpUserName === ''" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>SMTP User Name</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex: example@gmail.com"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field> <br>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="data.smtpUserPassword === ''" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>SMTP User Password</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex: password"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field> <br>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="data.smtpFrom === ''" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>SMTP From</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex: example@gmail.com"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field> <br>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="data.smtpDisplayName === ''" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>SMTP Display Name</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex: Jhon"></textarea>
        </mat-form-field> <br>
        <button mat-button (click)="saveXML()">Save</button>
     <!--    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <button mat-button (click)="saveXML()">Save</button>
        </mat-form-field> -->
    </form>
</div>
```

**EmailSettings.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, ChangeDetectorRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-EmailSettings',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './EmailSettings.html',
  
  })

  export class EmailSettings{
    appIdOpts: any = [];
    saveXML(){
        console.log("TestXML");
        let blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('formID').innerHTML], {type: "text/xml"});
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "blobExport.xml");
      }

  }
```

When I press on form's Save button I get the error `ERROR TypeError: _co.saveXML is not a function`.

[image]

I know that there is already [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580507/typeerror-co-function-is-not-a-function) about it, but didn't help me solve the error. What could I do?

---

**EDIT:**

As @SirOneOfMany suggested, I have created a new component, EmailSettings. My new structure is at follows:

[image]

As you have requested, my report-viewer.component.ts has the following content. Note that it contains some other functions which have no relevance to this topic. The function is relevant for us is called `openDialog()`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, ChangeDetectorRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import 'devexpress-reporting/dx-richedit';
import { DxReportViewerComponent } from 'devexpress-reporting-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import DevExpress from '@devexpress/analytics-core';
import List from "devextreme/ui/list";
import { DxSelectBoxModule, DxCheckBoxModule, DxListModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { ParagraphPropertiesKeepLinesTogetherDescriptor } from 'devexpress-richedit/lib/core/model/paragraph/paragraph-property-descriptors';
import { DxDropDownBoxModule, DxTreeViewModule, DxDataGridModule, DxTreeViewComponent, } from 'devextreme-angular';
import DXAnalytics from '@devexpress/analytics-core/dx-analytics-core'
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import { MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { EmailSettingsComponent } from '../email-settings/email-settings.component';  



@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-viewer',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './report-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    "./report-viewer.component.css",
    "../../../node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css",
    "../../../node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css",
    "../../../node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css",
    "../../../node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.common.css",
    "../../../node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.light.css",
    "../../../node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/css/dx-webdocumentviewer.css"
  ]

})



export class ReportViewerComponent implements OnInit {


  @ViewChild(DxReportViewerComponent, { static: true }) viewer: DxReportViewerComponent;
  @ViewChild('selectedReport', { static: false }) public selectedReport: "C:\\ReportDesigner\\Reports";
  @ViewChild("emailSettings", { static: true }) emailSettings: EmailSettingsComponent;

 // @ViewChild('selectedReport', { static: false }) public selectedReport: "@/Reports";

  treeBoxValue: 'selectedReport';
  isTreeBoxOpened: boolean;
  

  title = 'DXReportViewerSample';
  hostUrl = 'http://localhost:54111/';
  invokeAction: string = "/WebDocumentViewer/Invoke";
  reportUrl: string = 'Employee'; 

//some other functions here...

  ngOnInit() {
      var ajaxSetup = DXAnalytics.Analytics.Utils.ajaxSetup
    ajaxSetup.ajaxSettings = {
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
     }
  };
  }

  openDialog(){ //this functions is used to open the form which was on EmailSettings.html)
    this.dialog.open(EmailSettingsComponent, {
      data: {
       // animal: 'panda',
        smtpHost: '',
        smtpPort: '',
        smtpUserName: '',
        smtpUserPassword: '',
        smtpFrom: '',
        smtpDisplayName: '',
      },
    });
  }
}

export interface DialogData { 
  smtpHost: any;
  smtpPort: any;
  smtpUserName: any;
  smtpUserPassword: any;
  smtpFrom: any;
  smtpDisplayName: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-settings',
  templateUrl: 'email-settings',
})
export class EmailSettings {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}
```

At this point I get the error `ERROR in ./src/app/report-viewer/report-viewer.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './email-settings' in 'C:\ProiectVisualStudio\ProjectName\JS\angular-report-designer\src\app\report-viewer'`

Comment: Did you add your component to your declarations array in your app module? Btw you should use kebab notation when naming files and not pascal case. Or even better use ng schematics with ng generate to generate a component

Comment: Yes, report-viewer is in declarations array of app.module.ts. My guess is that there is a relationship problem between `EmailSettings.html` and `EmailSettings.ts`

Comment: No I meant your EmailSettings component. Every component that has a @Component decorator needs to be declared in a module

Comment: EmailSettings it's not created as a component, as report-viewer was created. What I did was just to create 2 files (EmailSettings.html and EmailSettings.ts) inside report-viewer component. As I wrote above, my guess is that there is a relationship problem between EmailSettings.html and EmailSettings.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in the comments section you will have to declare a component. Just adding a decorator is not enough.
Every class you add @Component(...) to needs to be added to the declarations array of a module.

I assume you just have one single AppModule class. So you will need to add your component to this module.

You used

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-EmailSettings',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './EmailSettings.html',
})
```

So you will need to add your EmailSettings class to your modules declarations array:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ReportViewerComponent, EmailSettings ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

That is why I said you should create your components with ng schematics, because angular already does this for you.

So just use:

```
ng generate component relative/path/in/src/folder/email-settings
```

This command will create the files for your component (.ts, .html, .(s)css, .spec.ts) and add the component to the closest module.

Have a look [at this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/) for a more precise explanation about modules

---

EDIT

Thanks for editing your question. At the very end of your report-viewer component you have the following that might throw an error

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-settings',
  templateUrl: 'email-settings', // this should throw the error
})
export class EmailSettings {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}
```

Remove that class and use your newly generated component. And as a small best practice hint:

Just implement only one class decorated via @Component per file

Use ng schematics to generate code, that way you can ensure your stuff is consistent through your whole app.

Give each interface a single file and move it to a models folder

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer! I did try 
`@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-settings',
  templateUrl: '././email-settings.html',
})` or `@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-settings',
  templateUrl: './email-settings.html',
})`
I'm still getting that error.  When you write "Just implement only one class decorated via @Component per file" it means that report-viewer.component.ts should have just a `@Component`, right? If yes, this means that relationship between these two components (report-viewer and emai-settings)l should be done differently. My questions is how?

Comment: The relationship is made via the module. That is why you need to add every component to the declarations array of your module. Remove your EmailSettings and just use your freshly generated component. The angular schematics generator should have added the component to the declarations array.

Comment: Ok. I've commented the entire @Component I was mentioning about. My app.module.ts declaration looks like this: `@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ReportViewerComponent,
    ReportDesignerComponent,
  //  EmailSettings,
    EmailSettingsComponent
],`
Now I'm getting `compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: EmailSettings cannot be used as an entry component.`. I think this is because of the `export class EmailSettings` from the last part of report-viewer.component.ts. This form was created based on an example found, if I remember correctly, on https://angular.io/

Comment: You should carefully read the tutorial again. From this distance I cannot debug your code for you. But as I mentioned before, use ng schematics to generate code, then use this generated assets in your app. Remove every @Component decorator from classes that are not added to your declarations array.
You could push your code to a github repo. This way I can see the whole app.module.ts and the rest of your code like the template

Comment: The tutorial is simple but I had to adapt it so the form can be opened from report viewer component. I will try to use  ng schematics to generate code. My app.module.ts: https://justpaste.it/4asqt

Comment: Also, sharing the project isn't a solution because my client app is linked to a server app which has connected several data bases. So to get running the client project would require quite an effort from you.  :)

Comment: An incipient form of my app can be found here: https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/Reporting_how-to-use-the-web-report-designer-in-javascript-with-angular-t566422. On the report-viewer.html I've added a button which opens the form with code listed above in EmailSettings.html.

Comment: remove the entryComponents array in your app module and you should be fine

Comment: I had to replace EmailSettings with EmailSettingsComponent in entryComponents. Now the form is displayed properly. The saveXML function is not working as expected, but this is another issue. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: No problem, but entryComponents is deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required

Please set my answer as correct if it helped you thx